# Get method for different classes in the model layer

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have a log functionality in my code, using this model

```
@Column(name = "OBJECT_ID")
private Long objectId;            <-- this is the id of the object of the logged class
@Column(name = "PROPERTY")
private String property;
@Column(name = "VALUE_BEFORE")
private String valueBefore;
@Column(name = "VALUE_AFTER")
private String valueAfter;
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "AUDIT_LOG_DEFINITION_ID")
private AuditLogDefinition auditLogDefinition;
```

For every different class that is being declared in the auditLogdefinition, we keep the information presented to the above model. The objectId is the id of the logged class.

I am also having an AuditLogView :

```
Long getObjectId();       <-- here i want to show the string from the getName() method of the previewed class 

String getProperty();

String getValueBefore();

String getValueAfter();

@Value("#{target.auditLogDefinition.getClassName()}")
String getAuditLogDefinition();
```

I tried to create a getName() method in the model that gets the class from the class name and get the name from that object but it is always empty. Which makes sense since I am not using the objectId anywhere.

I was thinking of making a custom query on the JPA repository but its unclear to me if i can return `List<AuditLogEntryView>` with the custom query.

What would be the best practice to follow here, to show the getName() field in my view?

Comment: Could you add the `getName()` you tried? Did you add a `@Value(...)` to it? What are the values of the properties you're refering to? Or do you mean that `objectId` is a reference to _another_ entity which you want to get the name of? In that case you'd very likely need to use a custom query as Spring wouldn't have any idea where to look for the object with that id (there might actually be many such objects, depending on how that id is defined).

Comment: @Thomas the getName() was stupid because i could not get the object for the selected class. ObjectId is the id of the specific object, from various classes logged. The objectId is unique to each object. Could it be possible for the query to return a list of AuditLogEntryView objects?? Not sure what the return types of a custom query could be.

Comment: Sure, a custom query can return lists just fine. You might want to read up on how to build custom queries in Spring repositories, the docs should contain all you need already. The trickiest part will be the actual SQL or JPQL query. How would you build that (SQL just using tables and JPQL just using the entity graph)? We lack information about your model so it's hard to help here but if I were to _guess_ I'd say unless your entities have a common super class (that's an entity itself and not just a mapped super class) JPA will struggle with finding an arbitrary object just by some id.

Comment: I would definitely check the documentation for that. I think it shouldn't be that hard because i already have the id and the class name and for that combination JPA should be able to provide me with the right on since there is only one match for this input. Thank you for the guidelines.

Comment: If the classname is just a property you might have to use 2 queries, i.e. 1st get the id and the class name and 2nd build a dynamic query using the class name. JPA will have a hard time resolving entities/tables for a query from within the query itself (so would plain SQL).